# Harnessing "computed properties aren't computed unless something tries to get them"

Tags: ember.js, service, ember-cli, inject, computed-properties

I'm learning Ember via ember-cli. I have a problem which I believe is related to "*computed properties aren't computed unless something tries to get them*", but I can't figure out how to "*get*" the property in this case. I created an app, one controller, one service, and one template using ember-cli:

```
ember new st
cd st/
ember g controller index
ember g service start
ember g template index
```

Controller:

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Controller.extend({
  start: Ember.inject.service(),
  value: Ember.computed('start', function () { 
    return this.get('start').value;
  }),
  actions: {
    update: function() {
      this.get('start').update();
      alert(this.get('start').value);
  }
 }
});
```

Service:

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Service.extend({
  value: "original",
  update: function() {
    this.set('value', "updated");
  }
});
```

Template:

```
<p>{{value}}</p>
<br>
<button {{action "update"}}>Update</button><br>
```

Then I serve this with "ember serve". As expected the value shown is the initial value "original". When I click the Update button, I get an alert showing the new value "updated" however the original value stays on the screen. How can I "*get*" this injected property such that it is computed and therefore updated?

ember-cli is 1.13.8, ember itself is 2.0.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are claiming to be dependent on the `start` property, but the `start` property itself isn't changing, the `value` property on `start` is.  You should change it to be dependent on the property `value` on `start`.  Additionally deeper properties can fetched within the `get` function.

```
export default Ember.Controller.extend({
  start: Ember.inject.service(),
  value: Ember.computed('start.value', function () { 
    return this.get('start.value');
  }),
  actions: {
    update: function() {
      this.get('start').update();
      alert(this.get('start.value'));
  }
 }
});
```

For kicks and giggles this could be written even easier two ways.

Use an alias:

```
export default Ember.Controller.extend({
  start: Ember.inject.service(),
  value: Ember.computed.alias('start.value'),
  actions: {
    update: function() {
      this.get('start').update();
      alert(this.get('start.value'));
    }
  }
});
```

Just reference it in the template

```
export default Ember.Controller.extend({
  start: Ember.inject.service(),
  actions: {
    update: function() {
      this.get('start').update();
      alert(this.get('start.value'));
  }
 }
});

<p>{{start.value}}</p>
<br>
<button {{action "update"}}>Update</button><br>
```

Comment: Thank you @Kingpin2k all 3 of your alternatives worked (_with the typo in the template corrected from service.value to start.value_). Much appreciated.